# Make a txt for each folder without space at the end of the filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Here is my code:

```
@echo OFF
for /d %%D in (*) do @echo %%~nxD >>List.txt
@ECHO ON
SET FileList=List.txt
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN (%FileList%) DO (
    ECHO ^0>"%%~F.txt"
)
GOTO EOF
```

My goal is to make `.txt` files with the name of each folder. For example for a folder named `Myfolder01` I want a `Myfolder01.txt` file.

But with my code, each filename have a space at the end: `Myfolder01 .txt`

What in my code is wrong? I don't want a space at the end of the filename.

Comment: if you don't want it, then don't write it. `>file.txt echo %var%` or `(echo %var%) > file.txt` are the most common methods. (the most obvious `echo %var%>file.txt` can fail in certain situations)

Comment: Do you really want a literal **0** stored in each file? If not then just use `type nul>"file.txt"` or `break >"file.txt"`. Also there is no need to do this with two `FOR` commands.  Just create the text file with the first `FOR` command.